# How to access only the related model with eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have these models in my project:

```
class User {

    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Favorite');
    }

}
```

-

```
class Product {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

-

```
class Favorite {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

}
```

When I try to get the user's favorites i will do like this:-

```
$user = User::find(1);
return $user->favorites;
```

Or with the products in his favorites:-

```
return $user->favorites->load('product');
```

But It returns the results from both (products and favorites).

**How do I get  the results only from Product model through the Favorite?**

Like I want to retrieve only the products that the user added to his favorites?

I already tried to  make this in the User class and it doesn't work:-

```
public function favproducts()
{
    return this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Favorite');
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want to do it by eloquent, Because you can do it by query.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do it using joins and stuff like that, But I prefer to do it in eloquent way.

Comment: You could try `$user->favorites()->with('product')->get()`

Comment: This exactly same as $user->favorites->load('product'); Which will return both models for me, I need only products without the favorites model

Comment: is this supposed to just be a pivot table between them?  and you didn't define the `favorites` relation on Product. can't go from Product to Favorite in your setup, which is how to get what you want.

Comment: Actually there is a favorites relation in my product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like this could be a `belongsToMany` between `User` and `Product` to make a 'favorites', as the pivot table.

Your current setup is missing the inverse relationship from `Product` to `Favorite`, so you can't use the relationship in that direction. Which is the direction I would use to get the result you want.

If you had the relationship setup, you could potentially do this to just get the Products for a User's favorites.

```
Product::whereHas('favorites.user', function ($q) use ($user_id) {
    $q->where('id', $user_id);
})->get();
```

Get all products that have a favorite that is for user with `id == $user_id`.

If this was setup for a `belongsToMany` you could potentially just do this instead:

```
User::find($id)->favorites;
```

With what you currently have, you could "fetch" the children records out of the result you have on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
in your case, i think it is a Nested Eager Loading

```
$user = User::with('favorites.product')->get();
//to grab the data
dd($user->favorites[0]->product);
```

hope it is help

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$user->favorites->product['name']
```

Comment: that would be trying to access the `product` property of a Collection